# Python VK-бот. Ошибка в передаче аргументов функции

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkbottle

VK бот, имеет меню, в котором четыре кнопки соответствуют выбору категории. В свою очередь, после выбора категории, в новом меню четыре кнопки будут соответствовать четырем элементам каждой категории. Элементы всех категорий хранятся в списке кортежей. Код вылетает с ошибкой при выборе категории, для идентификации категории в функцию должна передаваться переменная, соответствующей категории. В данном блоке кода:

```
...
@vk.on.private_message(text = (el for el in cat))
async def menu(message: Message, text):
    i = cat.index(text)
...
```

Происходит ошибка:

> TypeError: menu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

```
import asyncio
import requests
import random

from typing import Optional
from vkbottle import GroupEventType, GroupTypes, Keyboard, Text, VKAPIError
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from vkbottle import Keyboard, KeyboardButtonColor, Text, OpenLink
from vkbottle.tools import DocMessagesUploader

group_id = '' # enter group id
secret = '' # enter token

bot_token = secret
bot_group_id = group_id
vk = Bot(bot_token, bot_group_id)

cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4 = '1', '2', '3', '4'
cat = (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4)
items = [
('c1_1', 'c1_2', 'c1_3', 'c1_4'),
('c2_1', 'c2_2', 'c2_3', 'c2_4'),
('c3_1', 'c3_2', 'c3_3', 'c3_4'),
('c4_1', 'c4_2', 'c4_3', 'c4_4'),
]

# keyboard menu


@vk.on.private_message(text=[
    'Начать', 'начать', '/mm', 'menu', 'меню', 'Menu', 'Меню', 'Start', 'start',
])
@vk.on.private_message(payload={'cmd': 'menu'})
async def menu(message: Message):
    await message.answer(
        message='Меню: ',
        keyboard=(
            Keyboard(one_time=False, inline=False)
            .add(Text(cat1), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .add(Text(cat2), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .row()
            .add(Text(cat3), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .add(Text(cat4), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
        )
    )


@vk.on.private_message(text = (el for el in cat))
async def menu(message: Message, text):
    i = cat.index(text)
    await message.answer(
        message=cat,
        keyboard=(
            Keyboard(one_time=False, inline=False)
            .add(Text(items[i][0]), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .add(Text(items[i][1]), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .row()
            .add(Text(items[i][2]), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .add(Text(items[i][3]), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .row()
            .add(Text('Назад', payload={'cmd': 'menu'}))
        )
    )


@vk.on.private_message()
async def main(message):
    await message.answer('Be right back soon')


vk.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить следующим образом:

```
@vk.on.private_message(text = cat)
async def menu(message: Message):
    msg = message.text
    i = cat.index(msg)
    await message.answer(
        message=msg,
        keyboard=(
            Keyboard(one_time=False, inline=True)
            .add(Text(items[i][0]), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .add(Text(items[i][1]), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .row()
            .add(Text(items[i][2]), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .add(Text(items[i][3]), color=KeyboardButtonColor.POSITIVE)
            .row()
            .add(Text('Back', payload={'cmd': 'menu'}))
        )
    )
```